# Why Can not display image in email and i used codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Controller**

```
public function index() {

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/volunteer';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                var_dump($error);
            } else {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                send_mail('New Volunteer Form received', $this->load->view('site/email/volunteer', $data, TRUE));
            }
}
}
```

**Helper Function**

```
function send_mail($subject, $message) {

    /* @var $CI CI_Controller  */
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('upload');
    $CI->load->library('email');
    $CI->email->from('noreplay@xxx.com', 'Hello');
    $CI->email->to('xxx@xxx.com');
    $CI->email->subject($subject);
    $CI->email->message($message);
    $CI->email->set_mailtype('html');

    return $CI->email->send();
}
```

**View**

Below Table display image in email.

```
<table>
       <tr>
         <td>Photo</td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><img src="<?php base_url() ?>uploads/volunteer/<?php echo $file_name; ?>" height="100" width="150"></td>
                                </tr>
</table>
```

MY Quesion: why can not display image in my email and i am used codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

My English is not very good, please you will see it.

---

Maybe when you use the 

`<?php base_url(); ?>`

on your code.you maybe write like this:

`<?php echo base_url(); ?>`

the Url you should be use "echo",and then it will be show.

also,I don't know should you use / Symbol before "uploads/volunterr/".

you could see your email and use the firebug or chrome console to check the  src is ture or false.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<table>
       <tr>
         <td>Photo</td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>uploads/volunteer/<?php echo $file_name; ?>" height="100" width="150"></td>
                                </tr>
</table>
```

But Check if you have something configured inside the config file /application/config/config.php e.g.

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';